# Resize the UITextView when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I want to resize the text view when the keyboard appears. The code I have is below. I have auto layout on, hence using a constraint of textView->bottom space from superview and referencing it via IBOutlet distanceFromBottom.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    NSDictionary* d = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect r = [d[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    r = [textView convertRect:r fromView:Nil];
    if(IS_IPHONE_6||IS_IPHONE_6P)
      distanceFromBottom.constant = r.origin.y+78;
    else if(IS_IPHONE_5)
      distanceFromBottom.constant = r.origin.y+183;
  }];
}
```

The code above works perfect. What I don't understand is why I need to add +78 for iPhone6 or 183 for iPhone5. These two values I came with trial and error. If I don't add these, the textView extends below the keyboard. Please help me solve this mystery.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `viewWillAppear` method, add the following:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)paramAnimated{
    [super viewWillAppear:paramAnimated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        addObserver:self 
           selector:@selector(handleKeyboardDidShow:) 
               name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(handleKeyboardWillHide:)     
               name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];    
}
```

Then implement the two methods of the notification center, like this:

```
- (void) handleKeyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)paramNotification{

    NSValue *keyboardRectAsObject =
        [[paramNotification userInfo] 
            objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

    CGRect keyboardRect = CGRectZero;
    [keyboardRectAsObject getValue:&keyboardRect];

    yourTextView.contentInset =
        UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f,
                         0.0f,
                         keyboardRect.size.height,
                         0.0f);
}
```

And the other one like:

```
- (void) handleKeyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)paramNotification{

    yourTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

It will work for all devices ;)

Comment: Awesome sir. Worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 6):

**Swift / Modified Version**

Using the above, I made some adjustments to use `NSLayoutConstraint`'s changing the height `constant` property when the keyboard shows and hides. This also works if you rotate the device.

**1. Set up TextView Constraints**

Then control drag an outlet from you height constraint to the class.

[image]

**2. Add The Following**

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(SkillDescriptionViewController.keyboardWillShowHandle(_:)), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(SkillDescriptionViewController.keyboardWillHideHandle), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    }


    func keyboardWillShowHandle(note:NSNotification) {
        guard let keyboardRect = note.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
        let kbFrame = keyboardRect.CGRectValue()
        tvHeight.constant = -kbFrame.height
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func keyboardWillHideHandle() {
        tvHeight.constant = 0
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5 solution based on answers above**

Notification API has changed (20190707) as well as how to use `#selector`

The solution here can be used when the keyboard pop covers UITextView which causes user unable to see the text been edited.

```
import UIKit

class DCNodeLogEntryViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewNodeLogEntry: UITextView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(DCNodeLogEntryViewController.handleKeyboardDidShow(notification:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification,
            object: nil
        )

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(DCNodeLogEntryViewController.handleKeybolardWillHide),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
            object: nil
        )
    }

    @objc func handleKeyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let keyboardRect = notification
            .userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]
            as? NSValue else { return }

        let frameKeyboard = keyboardRect.cgRectValue

        textViewNodeLogEntry.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(
            top: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            bottom: frameKeyboard.size.height,
            right: 0.0
        )

        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    @objc func handleKeybolardWillHide() {
        textViewNodeLogEntry.contentInset = .zero
    }
}
```