# Resize UITextView when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uikeyboard

I try to resize the height of a UITextView-field when the keyboard appears (iOS 14.2, Xcode 12.3). The distance from the bottom of the UITextView to the save area is 90 and hence the lower part of it is hidden by the keyboard and can't be seen while editing.

I tried it with the solution shown here: [Resize the UITextView when keyboard appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992591/resize-the-uitextview-when-keyboard-appears)

Accordingly, my code is as follows:

```
class EditierenVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(false)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
               self,
               selector: #selector(EditierenVC.handleKeyboardDidShow(notification:)),
               name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification,
               object: nil
           )
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
               self,
               selector: #selector(EditierenVC.handleKeyboardWillHide),
               name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
               object: nil
           )
}


@objc func handleKeyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let endframeKeyboard = notification
                .userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]
                as? CGRect else { return }
    textfeld.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(
                top: 0.0,
                left: 0.0,
                bottom: endframeKeyboard.size.height-85,
                right: 0.0
            )
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

@objc func handleKeyboardWillHide()  {
    textfeld.contentInset = .zero
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}


//**************************
// MARK: - Views
//**************************


@IBOutlet weak var textfeld: UITextView!
```

Unfortunately the inset-size is not changed, when the keyboard appears and the text is partly hidden.
Has anyone an idea, why it  is not working?

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not come up with a solution by using content inset but I can suggest another way.

If you add bottom constraint to the textView and create outlet for that, you can change its constant value in notifications;

```
@objc func handleKeyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let endframeKeyboard = notification
                .userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]
                as? CGRect else { return }
    textViewBottomConstraint.constant = endframeKeyboard.size.height-85
}

@objc func handleKeyboardWillHide()  {
    textViewBottomConstraint.constant =  // set the previous value here
}
```

Comment: Together with the hint from #musakokcen I could fix it in the meantime. In the original setup I had the bottom constraint of the textView linked to a label below the textView, which itself had a height constraint and a bottom constraint to the save area. I replaced the bottom constraint of the textView to a direct relation to the safe area and then it work like described